# Plot each element in a list of tuples with different colours, based on its position in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

If you have a list of data points :

```
x = [(5, 1), (2, 4), (1,6), (4,7)]
```

how can you scatter plot these pairs such that each point has a different shade of a color? For example `(5,1)` could have a dark red, for being the first, `(2,4)` a slightly whiter red, and so on, until the last point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the color palette and manipulate the individual dots using `hue`. For exapmle:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [(5, 1), (2, 4), (1,6), (4,7)] 

cm = sns.color_palette('rocket',len(data))
plot = sns.scatterplot(x=[x[0] for x in data],y=[x[1] for x in data],hue=cm,legend=False,palette='rocket')
```

If you wish for a specific color progression, I suggest you then sort the data array previously.

Returns:

[image]

Comment: Great! Use sorted(data) for a dark to light progression while the x values increase, or modify as desired. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped solve your issue.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using Seaborn Hue and create a custom color palette using  hex color codes, which admittedly worked but.... Seaborn is worth installing and importing just for ease of use.

Comment: In this particular case, given OPs preference, the rocket palette kinda does what they want and allows for progression easily, but of course you could create your own custom-palette.

Comment: if you are "seaborn averse" `matplotlib` has several palettes that are easily implementable as well!

Comment: @AirSquid , correct, I got it to work with just `matplotlib` ... the missing ingredient was the color intensity for `c`

Answer (score 1):

You can use matplotlib's built in feature of `cmaps` for your scatter plot. It comes with an [array of choices](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html).

```
########## Recreating OP's data ############
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import log
x = [(5, 1), (2, 4), (1,6), (4,7)] 
testList2 = [(elem1, log(elem2)) for elem1, elem2 in x]
############################################

# Set the color intensity, just has to be unique numbers the length of your `x`
color_intensity = range(len(x))

# Use the cmap "Reds_r" to show darker red for lower number in the color intensity
plt.scatter(*zip(*testList2), c=color_intensity, cmap="Reds_r", edgecolors="black", s=100)
plt.show()
```

Graph:

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer, without the need to import seaborn!